# Does this variable need to be assigned in order for it to trigger a repaint?

Tags: javascript, browser

In browsers accessing certain properties will cause a repaint / reflow (see https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a). I'm wondering if it's necessary for the variable to be assigned for it to cause a reflow:

```
this.forceRepaint = function() {
  var _ = this.img.offsetWidth;
};
```

Or can I just return it (or do something even shorter)? Because it seems useless to assign it to a variable that isn't used.

Comment: You should call it `forceReflow`, not `forceRepaint`.

Comment: I'm curious what your use case for forcing a reflow would be? Usually you try to avoid those…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing magic about assigning the value you've read to a variable vs. doing something else with it. The reflow is caused by reading the value, not what you do with it.

As you say, you could return it:

```
this.forceRepaint = function() {
  return this.img.offsetWidth;
};
```

...but you probably don't even need to do that; just leave the property access:

```
this.forceRepaint = function() {
  this.img.offsetWidth; // Yes, this really is a valid statement
};
```

As [Bergi points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135861/does-this-variable-need-to-be-assigned-in-order-for-it-to-trigger-a-repaint/47135952?noredirect=1#comment81221572_47135952), the JavaScript engine can't optimize that property access away unless it knows that both the `img` and `offsetWidth` in `this.img.offsetWidth` are simple properties (not accessors), and of course in the case of an `img` element's `offsetWidth` property, it *is* an accessor (hence causing the reflow).

Comment: mate, u just posted it right before i could :) +1 for being super quick ;)

Comment: The variable assignment might be dead code, but I don't think a JavaScript engine is allowed to optimise away the property accesses. That is: not until it has proven they're not getters - but in the case of DOM access, they are.

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm refactoring someone else's plugin, so I'll remove it as soon as I have the rest cleaned up :)

Comment: @vsjn3290ckjnaoij2jikndckjb: FYI, I've updated the answer.